# MySQL grouping isn't respecting ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, group-by

I'm trying to do a MySQL query to find the most recently active threads (and the most recent comment on each thread) in a web forum. Threads are stored in two tables, `forum_topics` and `forum_responses`, where each `forum_topic` has many `forum_responses`.

Here, I do a search on `forum_reponses` joined to `forum_topics`, with a descending sort on `forum_response.id`:

```
select t.id, t.title, r.id, r.body 
    from forum_responses r 
    inner join forum_topics t on (r.forum_topic_id = t.id) 
    order by r.id desc;

+----+--------------+----+----------------------------------+
| id | title        | id | body                             |
+----+--------------+----+----------------------------------+
| 17 | New Topic    | 69 | yes                              |
| 19 | Test Topic 1 | 68 | This is a test                   |
| 17 | New Topic    | 64 | hey yo                           |
| 19 | Test Topic 1 | 63 | Test Topic Starter               |
| 18 | Test Topic   | 62 | Test.                            |
| 18 | Test Topic   | 61 | Test                             |
| 17 | New Topic    | 60 | Another test response.           |
| 17 | New Topic    | 59 | Test response.                   |
| 17 | New Topic    | 54 | What should this topic be about? |
+----+--------------+----+----------------------------------+
```

OK, so far so good. But it's returning duplicates - I just want to have the most recently-responded-to forum topics. So I add a GROUP BY to my query so we can group by the topic ID:

```
select t.id, t.title, r.id, r.body 
    from forum_responses r 
    inner join forum_topics t on (r.forum_topic_id = t.id) 
    group by t.id 
    order by r.id desc;

+----+--------------+----+----------------------------------+
| id | title        | id | body                             |
+----+--------------+----+----------------------------------+
| 19 | Test Topic 1 | 63 | Test Topic Starter               |
| 18 | Test Topic   | 61 | Test                             |
| 17 | New Topic    | 54 | What should this topic be about? |
+----+--------------+----+----------------------------------+
```

But now, we have a problem: It's grouping by the forum topic ID, but counterintuitively, we are not getting our forum topics sorted by most recent activity, and the associated forum responses are not the most recent.

What's going wrong here? Is there a way to alter this query so that I get a list of the most recently-contributed-to forum topics, along with their respective most recent comments?

Comment: If I understand your goal correctly... you'll need to group in a subquery to get the most recent response id for each topic, and then join that to the responses to get the body of the response.

Comment: You group by topic id. So you get one result line per topic. Now let's see what you show: its ID, its title, one of its response IDs, one of its response bodies. You order your results by some arbitrarily chosen response ID per topic. Why is it just one of the topics response IDs and bodies? Because you don't tell the DBMS which one you want. (But admittedly it is not easy in MySQL to tell it that).

Comment: You say you want to show the latest topics, but it seems you want to show *all* topics, each with its latest *response*. Or not? What exactly do you want?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I think you misunderstand Uueerdo here. If schnauss actually wants all topics with their latest response as it seems, you could go about this by finding the latest response id per topic (in a derived table query) and then use these to access the response records.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I didn't say anything about *ordering* in the subquery; I was saying the *grouping* must be in one. *Thorston understood and elaborated better.*

Comment: Can you provide some sample data at SQL Fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Diagnosis

The problem with your second query is that you are doing `GROUP BY t.id`, but the other columns being selected (`t.title`, `r.id`, and `r.body`) are not aggregate functions.  This is, in fact, an error under standard SQL, but MySQL won't complain unless you enable the server-wide `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting.  Instead, MySQL just gives you non-deterministic results.

### Suggested solution

```
select t.id, t.title, r.id, r.body
    from (
            select forum_topic_id, max(id) as id
                from forum_responses
                group by forum_topic_id
        ) as latest
        inner join forum_topics t on latest.forum_topic_id = t.id
        inner join forum_responses r on latest.id = r.id
    order by r.id desc;
```

### Beyond MySQL

With a more capable database, one would write this using window functions, also called analytic functions.  You could then avoid one of those joins.  On PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, or Oracle, the query would look more like this:

```
select t.id, t.title, r.id, r.body
    from (
        select forum_topic_id, id, body
            from forum_responses
            where 1 = rank(id over partition by forum_topic_id order by id desc)
        ) as r
        inner join forum_topics t on t.id = r.forum_topic_id
    order by r.id desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I was suggesting in my initial comment; you need to GROUP separately like so:

```
SELECT t.id, t.title, r2.id, r2.body 
FROM (
   SELECT forum_topic_id, MAX(id) AS lastResponseID 
   FROM forum_responses 
   GROUP BY forum_topic_id
) AS r
INNER JOIN forum_responses AS r2 
   ON r.forum_topic_id = r2.forum_topic_id AND r.lastResponseID = r2.id
INNER JOIN forum_topics AS t 
   ON r.forum_topic_id = t.id
ORDER BY t.id;
```

It *might* be faster (better able to take advantage of indexing) to include forum_topics (and it's `title` field) in the subquery, but that greatly depends on data distribution; joining millions of indexed rows (every response ever to their topic) can be slower than a relatively few unindexed ones (the most recent responses to their topic).

Comment: I see what you mean (AND on JOIN).

Comment: This is definitely not how I understood your original comment.  This is correct.